# Enabling "--enable-stdcall-fixup" flag with gnatmake?

Tags: ada, gnat

I'm using `gnatmake` to build my Ada project and I get the following warning:

```
Warning: resolving _LoadLibraryA by linking to _LoadLibraryA@4
Use --enable-stdcall-fixup to disable these warnings
Use --disable-stdcall-fixup to disable these fixups
Warning: resolving _GetProcAddress by linking to _GetProcAddress@8
```

I'm trying to pass `--endable-stdcall-fixup` to `gnatmake` but claims it's not a switch, how can I pass linker options through `gnatmake`?

```
gnatmake --enable-stdcall-fixup main.adb
gnatmake: invalid switch: --enable-stdcall-fixup
```

**(1) EDIT:**

Upon using the changes suggested by the answer, I still get the same error, yet it appears to be correctly passing to the linker this time.

```
gnatmake main.adb -f -largs --enable-stdcall-fixup
gcc -c main.adb
gcc -c winapi.ads
gnatbind -x main.ali
gnatlink main.ali --enable-stdcall-fixup
Warning: resolving _LoadLibraryA by linking to _LoadLibraryA@4
Use --enable-stdcall-fixup to disable these warnings
Use --disable-stdcall-fixup to disable these fixups
Warning: resolving _GetProcAddress by linking to _GetProcAddress@8
```

Comment: `-largs -foo` means to pass `-foo` to  gnatlink; but gnatlink is a front-end to the actual linker, and may not be passing it through to where it’s needed. Try `-largs -Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup` (`-Wl` means to pass through to the actual linker, `-Wc` to the actual compiler)

Comment: @SimonWright You were right! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `-largs opts`

From `gnatmake --help`:

> To pass an arbitrary switch to the Compiler, Binder or Linker:
>   -cargs opts   opts are passed to the compiler
>   -bargs opts   opts are passed to the binder
>   -largs opts   opts are passed to the linker
>   -margs opts   opts are passed to gnatmake

Comment: Hey, thank you for the details on `-largs` it seems to be passing correctly to the linker, yet still get the same error.